# How to solve Microsoft Access 2007 Exceptions?

Tags: c#, ms-access, connection-string

I'm having a difficult in `connectionString` in `Access 2007 Database` in `C#.Net`.
When I load `MainForm` ,the following Exceptions occur.
Please look at.

`System.InvalidOperationException: The ‘Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0′ provider is not registered on the local machine.`

after exception my `MainForm` close.
I thinks my PC need Access Driver to open that program.
I'm also developer of this program.
I wrote following `connectionString` in `app.config`

```
<add name="Constr2" connectionString="Provider=Microsoft.ACE.ODBC.12.0;Data Source=|DataDirectory|\InMyMind.accdb;Persist Security Info=True" providerName="System.Data.Odbc"/>
```

If I need a driver, how can should I do that?

Answer (score 1):

You need to install the OLE ODB Database Access driver on your machine.

You can normally find it in Control Panel.  What version of Windows do you use?

EDIT:

[This thread](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-IN/adodotnetdataproviders/thread/3d003721-6fb2-4927-9b29-bb6d7f35fa33) on MSDN seems to give you the answer to your issue.

Comment: Windows7 Ultimate,Please tell me how can find that driver and how to add my project.